# What does rank mean in relation to type conversion?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, type-conversion, rank

**From C++11 standard (draft n3337) §5/9:**

> — If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> — Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer
>   conversion **rank** shall be converted to the type of the operand with
>   greater **rank**.
>
> — Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has **rank**
>   greater than or equal to the **rank** of the type of the other operand,
>   the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of
>   the operand with unsigned integer type.
>
> — Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall be
>   converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> — Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer
>   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer
>   type.

**What does rank mean in this context?**
Surely it's not referring to [std::rank](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank),
as that has to do with the number of dimensions in an array...

In terms of integral types and floating point types, I think it refers to their potential sizes.

The C++ Standard guarantees that:

```
1 == sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <=  sizeof(long long)
```

am I right to assume then that the ranks are then:

<kbd>`Rank`</kbd><kbd>`Type`</kbd>     
<kbd>`1`</kbd>   <kbd>`char`</kbd>     
<kbd>`2`</kbd>   <kbd>`short`</kbd>    
<kbd>`3`</kbd>   <kbd>`int`</kbd>      
<kbd>`4`</kbd>   <kbd>`long`</kbd>     
<kbd>`5`</kbd>   <kbd>`long long`</kbd>
...

I haven't been able to find a [list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) anywhere describing the level of rank for each type.

Comment: See 4.13/p1 ([conv.rank]).

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yup, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: In the C spec: 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [4.13 section](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) says that

> Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>
> — No two signed integer types other than char and signed char (if char
>   is signed) shall have the same rank, even if they have the same
>   representation.
>
> — The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of
>   any signed integer type with a smaller size.
>
> — The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long
>   int, which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be
>   greater than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than the
>   rank of signed char.
>
> — The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the
>   corresponding signed integer type
>
> — The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank
>   of any extended integer type with the same size.
>
> — The rank of char shall equal the rank of signed char and unsigned
>   char.
>
> — The rank of bool shall be less than the rank of all other standard
>   integer types.
>
> — The ranks of char16_t, char32_t, and wchar_t shall equal the ranks
>   of their underlying types (3.9.1).
>
> — The rank of any extended signed integer type relative to another
>   extended signed integer type with the same size is
>   implementation-defined, but still subject to the other rules for
>   determining the integer conversion rank.
>
> — For all integer types T1, T2, and T3, if T1 has greater rank than T2
>   and T2 has greater rank than T3, then T1 shall have greater rank than
>   T3.